# Getting "node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build" error while installing "hummus-recipe"

Tags: npm

Command : "npm install hummus-recipe"

Error :
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hummus@1.0.95 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build $EXTRA_NODE_PRE_GYP_FLAGS`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hummus@1.0.95 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Any solution to this problem would be a big help !

Comment: I had a similar error, but as the error message says:  "There is likely additional logging output above." If you want help you need to include the actual error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Install `MuhammaraJS` package instead of `hummus-recipe`, which is no longer been maintained.
*"Muhammara-recipe and hummus-recipe has been integrated, dependencies updated and is now shipped along with muhammara itself.
It serves as a drop in replacement."*
[See Muhammara documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/muhammara?activeTab=readme)

Replace:

```js
const HummusRecipe = require('hummus-recipe');
```

with

```js
const HummusRecipe = require('muhammara').Receipe;
```